# JavaFX через Maven: cannot access javafx.application.Application

Tags: java, javafx, maven, jdk11

Решил добавить к проекту JDK 11 поддержку JavaFX, воспользовался самыми свежими зависимостями с репозитория Maven. В итоге ловлю ошибку на несоответствие версий. Пробовал более ранние зависимости - не помогло. Менять версию JDK не хочется, честно говоря.

Вот зависимости:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>12-ea+6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>12-ea+6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-base -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>12-ea+6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Версия JDK:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ошибка:

```
Error:(4, 26) java: cannot access javafx.application.Application
  bad class file: /Users/mainuser/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/12-ea+6/javafx-graphics-12-ea+6-mac.jar(javafx/application/Application.class)
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Как поправить? Отдельно добавлять в библиотеку нужный JAR? Хотелось бы все через мавен реализовать, всё-таки.

Comment: Где-то ниже в вопросах было про сборку javaFx 11 с помощью мавена.

Answer (score 1):

Это работает (меняйте JDK на 8-ку в настройках / установите дополнительно и поменяйте на 8-ку )! Зависимости для FX НЕ нужны.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, поменял-таки версию проекта на JDK 8. Зависимости убрал, все заработало.